# How to hide or disable the main toolbar in Octave (4.2)?

Tags: user-interface, octave, toolbar

The main toolbar has icons for "new file", "open file", a textbox for the current working directory and a couple of icons for browsing around. The bar stretches horizontally across the entire workspace but the icons only occupy around 40% of this. Even with icons set to "small" in Preferences, I am still losing around three lines of code on my MBP 13" screen.

Given the low value provided by the toolbar, the screen realestate tradeoff is extremely poor. Can we turn it off?

Note: This toolbar is not the same as the editor toolbar, which has icons for things like breakpoints and "step into".

Comment: Don't think there's a way to do this in 4.2. This was the first version of octave with a default GUI. I know there are a number of improvements worked into the next planned release, but no idea if this is part of it. I would recommend putting a feature request in at bugs.octave.org. a quick search might turn up something already, or they may let you know the likelihood if it being done. No chance though if no one asks.

Comment: I did a quick search and saw it had been raised a few versions ago. I'm just checking in with the community here to make sure I've not missed anything obvious.

Comment: btw, if space matters, why don't you use the cli?

Comment: I agree that the CLI is the most efficient on space but I (possibly naïvely) assumed it would be more difficult to do debugging. Can one debug through the command line interface?

Answer (score 0):

There is a crappy workaround where you detach the toolbar, drag the main window to the left, drag the toolbar to the right (so that it is 99% off screen) and then drag the main window back. This way the toolbar doesn't snap back into the workspace.

Sadly you still see a few pixels of the toolbar.